# VB. NET Syntax Error for query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

anyone help me with this?

```
pmc.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO  PreMainCheck(Department, PC_User, [Position/Designation], Date, Time, Frequency, Equipment_Type, Acquisition_Year, Brand, Model, Serial, c1, c1s, c2, c2s, c3a, c3as, c3b, c3bs, c3c, c3cs, c4a, c4as, c4b, c4bs, c4c, c4cs, c4d, c4ds, c4e, c4es, c4f, c4fs, c5, c5s, c6, c6s, c7a, c7as, c7b, c7bs, c8a, c8as, c8b, c8bs, c8c, c8cs, c8d, c8ds, c9a, c9as, c9b, c9bs, c9c, c9cs, c9d, c9ds, c9e, c9es, c10a, c10as, c10b, c10bs, c10c, c10cs, c10d, c10ds, c10e, c10es)VALUES(@dept,@user,@pos,@date,@time,@freq,@etype,@ayear,@brand,@model,@serial,@c1,@c1s,@c2,@c2s,@c3a,@c3as,@c3b,@c3bs,@c3c,@c3cs,@c4a,@c4as,@c4b,@c4bs,@c4c,@c4cs,@c4d,@c4ds,@c4e,@c4es,@c4f,@c4fs,@c5,@c5s,@c6,@c6s,@c7a,@c7as,@c7b,@c7bs,@c8a,@c8as,@c8b,@c8bs,@c8c,@c8cs,@c8d,@c8ds,@c9a,@c9as,@c9b,@c9bs,@c9c,@c9cs,@c9d,@c9ds,@c9e,@c9es,@c10a,@c10as,@c10b,@c10bs,@c10c,@c10cs,@c10d,@c10ds,@c10e,@c10es)")
```

Thank you. Truly appreciated on the answer.

Comment: Please consider formatting your code to make it as readable as possible.  One long line that requires us to scroll a long way horizontally is a great way to put people off helping you.

Comment: As for the issue, a syntax error in a query like that is most likely caused by a column name that is a reserved word.  I'm not scrolling to see what that might be but I'd suggest wrapping potential offenders in brackets until the issue goes way.

Comment: Yes, Date is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names for anything. Also advise not to use punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names.

Answer (score 0):

You also miss a space before VALUES:

```
pmc.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO PreMainCheck(Department, PC_User, [Position/Designation], [Date], [Time], <snip> ) VALUES(@dept,@user,@pos,@date,@time, <snip> )")
```